# Windows 11 File Explorer: menu bar with File, Edit, View and Tools appeared

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

As mentioned in the title, a [menu bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1NTb.png) appeared out of nowhere. I have tried every setting in *Folder options*. Restarting `explorer.exe` did not help. Any ideas on how to fix it?

**EDIT:** I fixed it by going to *Folder options/View* and unchecking *Always show menus*.

Comment: Try DISM /  SFC:    (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW  
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.    ..... If you can get to View options go down to Show and look through the list of things you can show.

Comment: I see the issue has been resolved now. BTW, can you tell us your Windows 11 OS version and build number?